# Override content from column "is_in_stock" in WooCommerce admin product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

I try to override content from column "is_in_stock" in WooCommerce admin product list.

For this I currently use:

```php
<?php
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'stock_override' );
 
function stock_override($column_name){
    global $post;
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    if( $product->is_type('variable')){
        if ($column_name == 'is_in_stock') {
            echo 'own text';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But this does not overriding the default content but add my text to this. The default content is the stock status `onstock`, `backorder` or `out of stock`.

I created an custom product type and I want override the content in the colum `is_in_stock` if the producttype is equal to variable. If is not equal echo the default from WooCommerce.

I can remove the whole column and add my own column but then I have no default content if the producttype is not equal.

Who can help me a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to delete the default column and replace it with a new one, you could just use the `woocommerce_admin_stock_html` filter where you have access to the `$product` object.

That way you can add your own text/statuses to the existing column.

So you get:

```php
// Admin product list: is_in_stock
function filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html( $stock_html, $product ) {
    // Condition
    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $stock_html = '<mark class="someclass" style="background:transparent none; color:#33ccff; font-weight:700; line-height:1;">' . __( 'My text', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';      
    }

    return $stock_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 10, 2 );
```